# Adjusting Points While Maintaining Line Network Node Connections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping, geometric-network, nodes

Currently I am working, within ArcGIS 10.4, on a pipe network for our water and sewer infrastructure which also contains all valves, hydrants, manholes, etc. These points are snapped to the line features, however, these are all assets that were converted from CAD and are not spatially correct.

Is there a way to adjust the points for the above ground assets, like shutoff valves, and it drag with it the vertices of the line it has previously been snapped to? The goal is to adjust the points features to a more correct location, without breaking the snapping of the lines to the point features, as well as, not breaking the node connections within each line feature class.

As a visual reference and example, you can see in the below image Hydrant 07-3-048 which is residing in the street. It needs to be moved about 10 feet east to the walkway against the darker building. I am wanting to move this hydrant point without losing the connection it has to the lateral water line, valve, and water main it is connected to.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in an edit session and you move a node, the connected lines and assets should come along with it and maintain their network connectivity. In an edit session, you can always undo or not save your changes if something goes wrong. I would probably test dragging the hydrant an extreme distance, like a block or two away, to make sure that everything followed, and then discard the changes before saving any of my real edits. Try making one small edit and saving, then run a trace to test for any breaks in connectivity. You can also manually reconnect any disjointed assets.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and both the points and line segment all separate from each other. I'm guessing this is not a true pipe network? Is there another way I can do this without a true network, assuming I was not told correctly?

Comment: Interesting.... perhaps your data hasn't been built into a geometric network. They're pretty easy to build. Just follow the instructions on the ESRI help: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/building-a-geometric-network-from-existing-simple-.htm. If you don't want a geometric network, then you pretty much have no choice but to edit each feature manually. You could also build a network to edit, then export back out to simpler data features after.

Comment: If you do have a geometric network, but some features aren't participating, you can append the new things in, or add them using one of the data loader options.